# Biathlon with inline skates

Tags: shooting, biathlon

I was wondering, whether there is some summer variant of biathlon - without cross-country skies. It might be fun to try racing on inline skates with shooting sessions. Is there already anything like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in Germany you can take part in a summer version organized by the DSB (German Shooting Federation) that consists of [running (in shoes) and shooting](http://www.dsb.de/sport/disziplinen/sommerbiathlon/).

Although this is the main variant, according to [the rules](http://www.dsb.de/sport/disziplinen/sommerbiathlon/regelwerk/):

> Summer Biathlon is an international competetive sport, combining two
>   different sports. Competitions of the DSB (German Shooting Federation)
>   mainly combine Cross country running with shooting with small-calibre rifle or air
>   rifle. Other combinations are possible for competitions, but are not
>   carried out as "German Championships". These could, in addition to
>   cross-country and shooting, consist of rollerski and shooting (Roller
>   Biathlon), **Inline/Cross-skater (Skike) and shooting**, mountain
>   biking and shooting, whereby in addition to shooting with
>   small-calibre rifle and air rifle, also laser rifles can be used,
>   particularly in urban or introductory events.

(my translation, and my bold)

I assume these biathlons with skates are mostly locally organized, and the local shooting club (Schützenverein) would have details.

One link I found was of a [team relay event in Saxony](http://www.activcamp-beer.de/inlineskate-biathlon-staffel/)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there sure is. It is called [summer Biathlon](http://www5.biathlonworld.com/en/press_releases.html?presse_kategorie=23) on the website of the International Biathlon Union. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Biathlon_World_Championships), there have even been organized World Championships in this discipline. As you expected, athletes make use of [Roller skiing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roller_skiing) instead of traditional cross-country skies.

Comment: I know about the variant with roller skies, but I'm curious about other variants.